# Getting RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on setTimeout even when the function being called is wrapped in a closure

Tags: javascript, closures, stack-overflow, settimeout

I have the following code, which when called repeatedly is throwing this error - 
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
var timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        onAnimationEnd(null);
    }, 2000)

onAnimationEnd : function(e) {
    if (e != null)
         e.stopPropogation();
    animatedObject.removeClass(this.triggerClass);
    animatedObject.unbind(this.endEventName);
    window.clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}
```

What are the possible scenarios in which this error can pop up other than calling the function directly?

Comment: what does onAnimationEnd do?

Comment: Seems like you are doing recursion with no termination condition.

Comment: It does a bunch of unbinds, removing classes and window.ClearTimeout(timeout)

Comment: Please share all relevant code... The code you've provided is not enough to help you out.

Comment: I've added the code for onAnimationEnd too.
The try/catch catches the error on the line window.setTimeout.

Comment: `this` in your code is not what you think it is, when `onAnimationEnd` is called from timeout.

Answer (score 0):

`this.timeout` won't work, you have the variable `timeout` in another scope, you should probably pass it as a paramter also:

```
var timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
    onAnimationEnd(null, timeout);
}, 2000);

onAnimationEnd(e, timeout) {
    if (e != null)
         e.stopPropogation();
    animatedObject.removeClass(this.triggerClass);
    animatedObject.unbind(this.endEventName);
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```